# Jquery script modification to add fade in/out features

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

Ok so I found this script from a different part of this site:

```
var divs = ["wrap20", "wrap21", "wrap22"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }

  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;

  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to successfully implement this code to a site which will show various groups of pictures whenever I click on an independent hyperlink.

What part of this code needs to be manipulated in order for the different elements to fade in or out?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    $(div).fadeIn(500);
} else {
    $(div).fadeOut(500);
}
```

500 is the number of milliseconds the fading should take. 
Here's a [working example with Jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/pythonpups/w84q027q/16/) on JSFiddle. 
Another possibility would be to use `show(500)` and `hide(500)`.

---

**UPDATE**:

Based on the OP's comments here's a version to achieve such an effect with  CSS transitions [(another Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/pythonpups/yss8jkb4/4/):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="a1" onclick="toggleVisibility('wrap20')">Click1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2" onclick="toggleVisibility('wrap21')">Click2</a>
<a href="#" id="a3" onclick="toggleVisibility('wrap22')">Click3</a>
<div>
    <div class="wraps on" id="wrap20">
      Image #1
    </div>
    <div class="wraps off" id="wrap21">
      Image #2
    </div>
    <div class="wraps off" id="wrap22">
      Image #3
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var divs = ["wrap20", "wrap21", "wrap22"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }

  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;

  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        div.className = "wraps on";
    } else {
        div.className = "wraps off";
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.wraps {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
}
.on {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  z-index: 999;
}
.off {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  z-index: 100;
}
#wrap20 {
  background-color:green;
}
#wrap21 {
  background-color:blue;
}
#wrap22 {
  background-color:red;
}
```

You don't need the `display` property here, it's not fit for transitions anyway. You just display all the divs like you want them and use the `opacity` property to hide and show them. `opacity` works well with transitions. `Transition` and `opacity` for the two states are rolled up in classes so you don't have to set them separately in your javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Modifying that part of the script actually rendered the whole script useless.

Comment: Well, what I did was make the changes on the actual web page instead of putting it on the console. I clicked the links and basically nothing appeared.

Comment: Uhm no, I mean, in the Development tools (you can reach that by rightclicking and choosing "inspect element", depending on the browser you use) there's the Javascript console, displaying error messages, messages by `console.log()` and the like. If anything shows up there after reloading the page or firing an event, that's usually very helpful for debugging. Could you have a look?

Comment: Ok gotcha. I ran the Development tools, and after changing to the suggested fade entries, the debugger is telling me that '$' is undefined where it says, "$(div).fadeout(500); . A site that I referenced, and whose source I copied to my local machine, is this: http://jsbin.com/Ipezadu/1/

Comment: That means that you do not have Jquery active. Indeed none of your code uses it up to now, though you tagged the question jquery. To use it include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head.

Comment: Some-non-descript-user I just tried what you suggested and unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Some-non-descript-user I have a question. I'm looking at the section where it says, if(visibleDivID === divId) {... etc... There's the condition for div.style.display = "block". What would I have to do to enter an additional condition. I'd like it to say something like div.style.display = "block" and div.style.transition = "all 2s." Is that even possible?

Comment: See my updated answer. You might want to add an approprite tag to the question.

Comment: @michael-lopez Is this about what you intended...?

Comment: some-non-descript-user It's getting close. I took your example and tailored it to fit the web site that I've developed. The web site is :http://www.miguelonenterprises.com/scrollbody_with_fade.htm. What you will see is, when you click the 1st set hyperlink; you will see 5 thumbnails. You will also see a scrollbar to the far right. Obviously those 5 thumbnails shouldn't prompt a scrollbar to be visible. Secondly, if you were to click on the thumbnails on the 1st set, they will automatically reference the thumbnails on the second set. It's as if the 2nd set dominates the page landscape.

Comment: We're almost there, I think. It looks as if we may have just a small few technicalities to overcome.

Comment: The clickability problem can be solved by adding `z-index: 999` to `.on` and `z-index: 100` to `.off`. That will move the active element to the top in the stack. I updated the CSS-method fiddle. The scrollbar problem can't be solved that way 'cause the elements are still there, only transparent. To make the scrollbar go away you'd have to use `display: none`, which is not useful for transition. That'd be a job for Jquery. I'll update...

Comment: Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/pythonpups/choqachk/ Jquery's `fadeIn/Out` functions will do all you need. Btw. you use the `fade1`-Id multiple times in your HTML. That can give you trouble because Ids must be unique.

Comment: some-non-descript-user Thanks for the feedback. I'll have a look at it within the next day or so and let you know what I find.

Answer (score 0):

some-non-descript-user Ok I tried your Jquery fiddle, and that is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks for your patience and time.